# If one had to sleep the maximum amount possible during a 24 hour period, how should he arrange his prayers?

Tags: tefilla

If one had to sleep the maximum amount of time possible during a 24 hour period, **In which order, and at what times of the day** should he arrange his Tefillos?

For example should he start with Maariv right before daybreak, continue with Shacharis at daybreak, and then daven Mincha at the beginning of Mincha Gedola time, and then sleep until the next morning before daybreak for Shacharis etc.,
Or would some other arrangement give him more sleep hours?

Comment: Mightn't one be entirely exempt from prayer in such a case?

Comment: Where and when is this person? Can they sleep in multiple stints? Do they need to say Keriat Shema on time too? How much time is needed for falling asleep and getting up? (What is the point of this question??)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that one should finish shacharit before 8 am, (example) and go to sleep right after that. Then wake up 15 min. before shkiya and daven Mincha, and right after Shkiya, daven Maariv, then wait till Tzeit Hakochavim, say Shema and go back to sleep till 8am. Daven Shacharit after the 24 hour period is over.

This way, he only has to wake up once for mincha and maariv.